# Congugate Gradient Sparse Matrix Solver using C#

Tags: c#, sparse-matrix

I'm looking forward to a transferred algurithm of Congugate Gradient sparse matrix solver into C#.
if anyone has the C# code of CG or PCG let me know.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this could help you, but to be honest this doesn't seem like a very well thought-out question.

http://www.koders.com/csharp/fidA522A433065B5D359C943562507882606B1AD25D.aspx?s=search